# A locally constant sheaf on a locally connected space is a covering space; Proof?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, covering-spaces, topos-theory

As part of my hobby i'm learning about sheaves from Mac Lane and Moerdijk. I have a problem with Ch 2 Q 5, to the extent that i don't believe the claim to be proven is actually true, currently. Here is the question repeated:

> A sheaf on a locally connected space $X$ is *locally constant* if each point $x \in X$ has a basis of open neighborhoods  $\mathcal{N}_x$ such that whenever $U,V \in \mathcal{N}_x$ with $U \subset V$, the restriction $\mathcal{F}V \rightarrow \mathcal{F}U$ is a bijection. Prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally constant iff the associated etale space over $X$ is a covering.

I don't have a problem (i think) showing the "covering" $\rightarrow$ "locally constant" direction of the implication. My problem is in the reverse direction. In fact, in the process of trying to solve this problem i think i have come up with a very simple counterexample.

Here's my attempt at a counterexample:

Let $X = \{a,b,c\}$ be  finite space with open subsets $\{\{\},\{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\}\}$. I claim this is hyper-connected and locally connected.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the sheaf with $\mathcal{F}(\{a,b,c\}) = \{q\}$, $\mathcal{F}(\{a,b\}) = \{r,s\}$, and $\mathcal{F}(\{a\}) = \{t\}$, where $r = q|_{\{a,b\}}$, and $t = q|_{\{a\}} = r|_{\{a\}} = s|_{\{a\}}$. I claim this defines a locally constant sheaf. Indeed we can have $\mathcal{N}_{a} = \{\{a\}\}$, $\mathcal{N}_{b} = \{\{a,b\}\}$, and $\mathcal{N}_c = \{\{a,b,c\}\}$.

Now we can calculate the corresponding etale space $p : E \rightarrow X$ as follows: $E = \{\dot{q}(a), \dot{q}(b), \dot{q}(c), \dot{s}(b)\}$, and has these four distinct elements since $\dot{q}(a) = \dot{r}(a) = \dot{s}(a) = \dot{t}(a)$, and $\dot{q}(b) = \dot{r}(b)$. The action of $p$ follows by construction.

However, $p$ does not appear to me to be a covering space. In particular, the only neighborhoods of $b \in X$ are $\{a,b\}$and $\{a,b,c\}$ and we have $p^{-1}(\{a,b\}) = \{\dot{q}(a),\dot{q}(b),\dot{s}(b)\}$ and this cannot be partitioned into homeomorphic images of $\{a,b\}$ because $2 \nmid 3$. Similarly, $p^{-1}(\{a,b,c\}) = \{\dot{q}(a), \dot{q}(b), \dot{q}(c), \dot{s}(b)\}$ and this cannot be partitioned into homeomorphic images of $\{a,b,c\}$ since $3 \nmid 4$.

So i think i have a locally constant sheaf on a locally connected space whose corresponding etale space is not a covering. What have i done wrong? I have seen the claim mentioned elsewhere so i'm convinced i'm wrong somewhere. Perhaps someone knows where a correct proof is published otherwise?

Comment: I don't think $\mathscr{F}$ is a locally constant sheaf: the restriction of $\mathscr{F}$ to $\{ a, b \}$ is not a constant sheaf.

Comment: Zhen, are you appealing to a property that locally constant sheaves need to be constant on connected subcomponents of the space? If so how do you get from the property as defined in the question to that?

Comment: Ah, they have a different definition... and a strange one at that. I suspect it doesn't work well in a non-Hausdorff space. Here is what I would use: a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ is locally constant if there exists an open cover of the space such that the restriction of $\mathscr{F}$ to each open set in the cover is a constant sheaf.

Comment: Thanks Zhen. I've looked over my example a few times and i still cannot see a mistake, so i'm wondering whether their definition is too weak.

Comment: I gave this some more thought and it seems to me the definition used in the question quoted above is too weak even when $X$ is quite well-behaved. Consider for example $X$ the real line and $A$ the discrete space with elements $\{a,b\}$ say. There is a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ with sections those continuous maps $s : U \rightarrow A$ with $0 \notin s^{-1}(\{b\})$. I think this satisifies the definition of "locally constant" but not the one used by @ZhenLin nor is its etale space a covering ... maybe they should have used "if" instead of "iff" when writing the question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am posting this just to confirm that the definition of locally constant as given in the OP (and I guess in the text that the OP is citing) is incorrect.

A sheaf is called *locally constant* if each point has a n.h. on which it becomes consant.  This is a stronger condition than that in the OP, and it is true that a sheaf is locally constant iff the associated etale space is a covering space (perhaps under mild conditions such as local connectedness --- I haven' thought 
it through for a while).

The condition in the OP is much weaker: it just says that the transition maps in
the definition of the stalk of $\mathcal F$ at each point $x$ are eventually constant, and many kinds of sheaves will satisfy this condition, e.g. skyscrapes, sheaves such as $j_!\mathbb Z$ (say for $j$ being the inclusion of an open set in a variety), and more generally (I think) any constructible sheaf on a variety over $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 5):

I realize it's been a while since the original question was posted, but I've run into the same issue with the same question. I don't believe it's true as written, either. Here is my counterexample: let $X$ be a metric space and let $A$ be a set with more than one element. Then given $x \in X$, $\mbox{Sky}_x(A)$ is locally constant under the definition given in the problem. If $y \neq x$, then take as the neighborhood basis at $y$ the balls $$B\bigg(y;\frac{d(x,y)}{2^n}\bigg).$$ The restriction morphisms between these neighborhoods are obviously bijections, since the sets are all singletons. At $x$, we may take the neighborhood basis to be all open sets, and the restriction morphisms are again bijections, since they are all identity on $A$.

However, the bundle of sections for this sheaf is not a covering space. The fiber at $x$ consists of $|A|$ points, while the fiber at all other points consist of only one point. A covering space has fibers whose size are locally constant, so the associated bundle is not a covering map.